# Change JavaScript params using h:selectOneMenu

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to use this chart and reload it using h:selectOneMenu with new data:

```html
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_e6df2"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     new TradingView.widget(
      {
         "autosize": true,
         "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
         "interval": "D",
         "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
         "theme": "Light",
         "style": "1",
         "locale": "uk",
         "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
         "enable_publishing": false,
         "allow_symbol_change": true,
         "container_id": "tradingview_e6df2"
      }
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

JSF code:

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{dashboard.symbol}" class="form-control" name="symbolid">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="NASDAQ:BCH/BTC" itemLabel="BCH/BTC"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="NASDAQ:AAPL" itemLabel="AAPL"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I would like to update `"symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL"`, with some custom param from the select menu and reload the chart.

Do you know how I can implement this functionality?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{dashboard.symbol}" class="form-control" name="symbolid">                                                            
  <f:selectItem itemValue="NASDAQ:AAPL" itemLabel="BCH/BTC"/>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="XBTUSD" itemLabel="BCH/EUR"/>
  <f:ajax event="change" render="tradingview_1f8e8" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Chart:

```
<div id="tradingview_1f8e8" class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "#{dashboard.symbol}",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "uk",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_1f8e8"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `"symbol": "#{bean.symbol}"`?

Comment: But how to reload TradingView JavaScript Object?

Comment: By learning the basics of jsf and ajax and update the  part the javascript is in...

Comment: I updated the post with ajax event but nothing happens.